# The output size of theano.tensor.nnet.conv.conv2d

Tags: python, theano

The function that is currently being used widely on tutorials and other place is of the form:

```
conv_out = conv2d(
        input= x, # some 4d tensor 
        filters= w, # some shared variable
        filter_shape= [ nkerns, stack_size, filter_height, filter_width ],
        image_shape= [ batch_size, stack_size, height, width ]
    )
```

1. If for the first layer of a CNN, I have `filter_shape` as `[ 20, 1 , 7, 7 ]` which is the number of kernals being 20, each 7 X 7, what does the '1' stand for ? My `image_shape` is `[100, 1, 84, 84 ]`.
2. This convolution now outputs a tensor of shape `[ 100, 20, 26, 26]` which I understand. My next layer now takes the parameters `filter_shape` = `[50, 20, 5 ,5 ]` , `image_shape` = `[ 100, 20 ,26, 26 ]` and produces a output of shape  `[ 100 ,50 ,11 ,11 ]`. I seem to kind of understand this operation, except, if I want to use a '50' filters layer each working on previous 20 feature maps produced, shouldn't I produce 1000 feature maps in all instead of producing just 50 feature maps ? To restate my question, I have a stack of 20 feature maps each running 50 kernals of convolution, shouldn't my output shape be `[100, 1000, 11, 11]` instead of `[ 100, 50 , 11, 11]` ?

Comment: Actually, can you explain how you get an output tensor of [100, 20, 26, 26]? That is exactly what I'm struggling with. I thought the convolution is a filter of shape 7x7 that strides over the input image, I'd think the output tensor is then 100 x 1 x 84-7 x 84-7... Your pointers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. The `1` stands for the number of input channels. As you seem to be using gray scale images, this is one. For color images it can be 3. For other convolutional layers as in your second question, it must be equal to the number of outputs that the previous layer generated.
2. Using a filter of size `[50, 20, 5, 5]` on an input signal of `[100, 20, 26, 26]` is actually a good example for your first question, as well. You have here 50 filters of shape `[20, 5, 5]`. Every image is of shape `[20, 26, 26]`. The convolution uses all the 20 channels each time: Filter 0 gets applied to image channel 0, filter 1 gets applied to image 1, and the whole result gets summed up. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry if this seems like a really basic question but why does the whole result get summed up? This seems to be the status quo in every forum/paper I read and the reason is not made clear. Same as the OP, I was under the impression that when a number _n_ of feature maps is produced, the next layer would, in turn, do a convolution on every single one of those. Any suggestions on something I could read to help me understand the theory behind this?

Comment: I guess that is standard practise that has proved effective for eg object recognition in terms of what type of function that permits you to learn. You can also not do it if you want. E.g. the scattering transform doesn't do it. There may also be one or two papers now or in the future showing that you don't necessarily need that to learn

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :)